# How to start a secondary rails app during rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have 2 rails apps. One is a web interface (I'll call it *UI*), the other one is an API server (I'll call it *API*).

They interact together, UI is sending json commands to API. I want to test all of this in integration. Today I manually start API from the command line, and I am looking for a way to automatically start the API server from the test suite.

I am using Capyraba, Selenium, Rspec. During the tests Capybara automatically starts a UI server, I need to also start a API server.

Any hint appreciated. Thanks

---

I tried `Process.spawn("cd /api/project/path && rails s -e test")` but I get a `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches` error saying that the path in API is not existing. But when I run API manually I don't have this error.

I believe Rack is getting confused with 2 environments

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that API is running before your scenarios are started. You can add rule to start it if it is not running by adding in `before` hook:

```
#features/supports/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb
Before do |scenario|
  start_api()   
end

def start_api()
 Process.spawn("./script/server start")
end
```

Comment: `system` is blocking, isn't it?

Comment: better to use `Process.spawn`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sadly it does not work. I got `Rack app error handling request { POST /api/path/i_m/testing }
#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/api/path/i_m/testing">`. Off course this error is not raising when I start APi manually.